# Python Error TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to this area, help make out the mistake

```
name = input( "Enter your name:"  ) 
age = 12
print( "Hi, " + name + " " + age + " years old!" )

$ python test.py
Enter your name:evgen
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
print( "Hi, " + name + " " + age + " years old!" )
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Comment: A more "modern" and easy way of dealing with strings is use format. Specifically `f-strings`: `print(f"Hi, {name} {age} years old!")`

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert int to str before concatenating:

```
name = input( "Enter your name:"  ) 
age = 12
print( "Hi, " + name + " " + str(age) + " years old!" )
```

Also have a look at string formating with python: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-examples

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating string with integer `age`. Simply cast /convert `age` to `str` like this:

```
print( "Hi, " + name + " " +str(age) + " years old!" )
```

Comment: That's not how string conversion works in python.

Comment: Yes I have edited it my bad. The previous parenthesis way works in php. So I got confused in syntax !